# How many alphabetic string are there whose length is at most five?

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling with a problem from my text book, and was wondering if I am on the right path. I know I need to combine the amount of length $1$ strings all the way to length $5$ strings. I just do not know if I am doing it right.

What I have is $\binom{26}{5}+\binom{26}{4}+\binom{26}{3}+\binom{26}{2}+\binom{26}{1}.$

I am sorry to just ask a am I on the right path question, but I am stuck and this concept is important through the rest of the chapter.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: you have the right idea, just make sure you calculate "chose" correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is important when counting strings, and you must also consider repetition. If we have an alphabet with two letters $a$ and $b$ then the amount of strings of length two is $4=2^2$, namely $aa$, $ab$, $ba$ and $bb$. However $\binom{2}{2}=1$.